# Ncdu is filled with ?~V~H garbled symbols after a reinstall of macOS Monterey

Tags: macos, homebrew, terminal.app

On my newest re-install of macOS Monterey [`ncdu`](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) suddenly looks really weird.

A lot of the directories are shown with `?~V~H` behind and next to them.

This issue persists across multiple Terminal profiles.
I tried reinstalling `ncdu` in home-brew to no avail.

Am I missing some important dependency or what is going on here?

Here is a screenshot of the issue:

[image: screenshot]

Edit: Downgrading to version 2.01 of Ncdu fixed the issue.

Comment: As a wild guess, this is installed via brew or something similar? If so, do you have the correct ncurses version ("ncursesw" is needed to support 'wide' characters)?

Comment: Thank you for responding. Everything seems to be fine with ncurses. I have 6.3. Edit: I figured out that it was because of ncdu version 2.1. Installing 2.01 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was fixed by downgrading to version 2.01 of `ncdu`.

Since I installed with Homebrew it was real easy. Just set up your own tap beforehand.

```
brew extract --version 2.0 ncdu (personal tap)
brew install ncdu@2.0
```

For some reason I needed to write version 2.0 to get 2.01.
A bit weird, but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

ncdu in the latest versions does not play well with non utf-8 locales.

I had the same issue on Archlinux. It was fixed when I set the LANG environment variable to en_US.UTF-8 (used to be C). Be sure to set your locale to something that is utf-8 based and it should work alright even with the latest version.